# Openfire meeting - Jitsi Conference Failed Connection Error

Tags: xmpp, openfire, jitsi, jitsi-meet

We are trying to deploy our Jitsi Meet instance. We've installed Openfire Meeting Plugin. I can see that the plugin was installed successfully. When I access the Jitsi URL `/ofmeet/DemoMeeting1` it prompts me for username and password. After entering both it logs me in. However, I get the following error:

[image: Connection failed]

Here are the browser logs, I see in chrome.

```
    Jitsi2:9 (TIME) index.html loaded:   467.68999999039806
Logger.js:125 [modules/browser/BrowserCapabilities.js] <new t>:  This appears to be chrome, ver: 81.0
LocalStatsCollector.js:22 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. goo.gl/7K7WLu
(anonymous) @ strophe.js:53
Logger.js:125 [react/index.web.js] <HTMLDocument.<anonymous>>:  (TIME) document ready:   1986.1649999947986
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/storage/PersistenceRegistry.js] <e.value>:  redux state rehydrated as Object
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.changeUserAvatar>:  Missed avatar update - no small video yet for undefined
o @ index.js:1
Logger.js:125 [JitsiMeetJS.js] <Object.init>:  Analytics disabled, disposing.
i @ strophe.js:53
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/AnalyticsAdapter.js] <e.value>:  Disposing of analytics adapter.
i @ strophe.js:53
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/ScreenObtainer.js] <Object.init>:  Desktop sharing disabled
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/media/middleware.js] <>:  Start muted: 
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/media/middleware.js] <>:  Start audio only set to false
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/conference/middleware.js] <>:  Audio-only disabled
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCUtils.js] <t.value>:  Using the new gUM flow
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  P2P STUN servers:  Array(3)
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connecting:  2436.8649999960326
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCUtils.js] <t.<anonymous>>:  Got media constraints:  Object
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCUtils.js] <>:  onUserMediaSuccess
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connfail[x-strophe-bad-non-anon-jid]:    4145.414999991772
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe disconnecting[x-strophe-bad-non-anon-jid]:   4146.200000002864
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe disconnected:    4147.40499999607
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/statistics.js] <Function._.sendAnalyticsAndLog>:  {"type":"operational","action":"connection.failed","attributes":{"error_type":"connection.passwordRequired"}}
Logger.js:125 [connection.js] <r.c>:  CONNECTION FAILED: connection.passwordRequired
o @ index.js:1
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  P2P STUN servers:  Array(3)
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connecting:  10563.394999990123
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connected:   13849.285000003874
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  My Jabber ID: justin.credible@server01.com/1hh1yloy01
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <>:  initialized with 2 local tracks
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <new t>:  Joined MUC as jitsi2@conference.server01.com/justin-credible-d39f32
Logger.js:125 [modules/e2eping/e2eping.js] <new e>:  Initializing e2e ping; pingInterval=10000, analyticsInterval=60000.
Logger.js:125 [modules/connectivity/ParticipantConnectionStatus.js] <new e>:  RtcMuteTimeout set to: 2000
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/AvgRTPStatsReporter.js] <new e>:  Avg RTP stats will be calculated every 15 samples
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <new z>:  backToP2PDelay: 5
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  Last visible video no longer exists
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  Fallback to local video...
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  electLastVisibleVideo: undefined
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <z._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no JVB JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <z._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no P2P JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <z._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no JVB JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <z._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no P2P JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <d.setFocusUserJid>:  Focus jid set to:  focus@server01.com
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <d.createConferenceIq>:  Session ID: null machine UID: b18ecd98d476e7e7c66dc547a12692b1
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/LargeVideoManager.js] <>:  hover in %s undefined
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/tracks/actions.js] <>:  Replace audio track - unmuted
Logger.js:125 [react/features/base/tracks/actions.js] <>:  Replace video track - unmuted
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/strophe.ping.js] <s.value>:  XMPP pings will be sent every 10000 ms
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <d.parseConfigOptions>:  Authentication enabled: false
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <d.parseConfigOptions>:  External authentication enabled: false
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <d.parseConfigOptions>:  Sip gateway enabled:  false

Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <t.value>:  onPresError  <presence xmlns=​"jabber:​client" to=​"justin.credible@server01.com/​1hh1yloy01" from=​"jitsi2@conference.server01.com/justin.credible-d39f32" type=​"error">​…​</presence>​<x xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jabber.org/​protocol/​muc">​</x>​<c xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jabber.org/​protocol/​caps" hash=​"sha-1" node=​"http:​/​/​igniterealtime.org/​ofmeet/​jitsi-meet/​" ver=​"12a0JlElgsvtkqcjvfNtayNtIdw=">​</c>​<avatar-id>​36105051c62f5a740aa3f9b498b355e1​</avatar-id>​<nick xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jabber.org/​protocol/​nick">​Change ​</nick>​<audiomuted xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jitsi.org/​jitmeet/​audio">​false​</audiomuted>​<videoType xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jitsi.org/​jitmeet/​video">​camera​</videoType>​<videomuted xmlns=​"http:​/​/​jitsi.org/​jitmeet/​video">​false​</videomuted>​<error code=​"407" type=​"auth">​…​</error>​</presence>​
i @ strophe.js:53
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  Last visible video no longer exists
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  Fallback to local video...
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/VideoLayout.js] <Object.electLastVisibleVideo>:  electLastVisibleVideo: justin.credible-d39f32
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <e.value>:  CONFERENCE FAILED: conference.connectionError
o @ index.js:1
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/LargeVideoManager.js] <>:  hover in %s justin.credible-d39f32
```

On the Openfire server I can see that Group Chat is created but room occupants only contain focus user.
[image: Group Chat - Room Occupants]

Can anyone please analyze what could be the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: How I love "something" messages without details. If `<error code=​"407" type=​"auth">` is HTTP then it means "Proxy Authentication Required", whatever that means to your network.